# Using Spark 'CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION' with Python file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The Spark SQL syntax can [register a UDF from SQL](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-function.html) with

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION simple_udf AS 'SimpleUdf'
USING JAR '/tmp/SimpleUdf.jar';
```

Is it possible to do the same with Python ? Something like:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION simple_udf AS 'SimpleUdf'
USING FILE '/tmp/sample_udf.py';
```